# Creating a WP plugin and having issues linking CSS stylesheet within functions

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-style

Creating a WP plugin for third party usage (first time doing this), and typically links to stylesheets are put in the header or in the theme generated options panel.  That's fine for personal use but not for this.

I found wp_enqueue_style via a search on here, and I'm trying to apply it.  Below is the code I have right now.

```
function wpse_load_plugin_css() {
    $plugin_url = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', $plugin_url . 'style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_load_plugin_css' );




function test() {
global $con;
wp_enqueue_style('style');

   ** the bulk of my code - query and output **

}
```

None of my styling is working at this point.  I've cleared the cache, and this early stage, just trying to change the size of fonts.

EDIT:
Directory:
/wp-content/plugins/player-match/

Both functions are on the same file pm_main.php.  style.css is in the same directory.

Am I on the right track?

Thank you.

Comment: "That's fine for personal use but not for this." - why, and what are you really trying to do? Why do you call `wp_enqueue_style()` twice? But if you're trying to manually print the `<link>` tag in the `body`, then note that the MDN web docs [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link), "*`<link rel="stylesheet">` is permitted in the body. However, this isn't a good practice to follow; it makes more sense to separate your `<link>` elements from your body content, putting them in the `<head>`*".

Comment: There are a few examples saying to do so without a clear way of utilizing it.  This link dug a little deeper:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760222/how-to-include-css-and-jquery-in-my-wordpress-plugin

Comment: I think I misread the "are put" in "typically links to stylesheets are put in the header or...", i.e. you're now just trying to enqueue the stylesheet manually via `wp_enqueue_style()` and it's not working for you, right? And if so, then I guess you're not using the correct hook - if `test()` is used on an admin page (like a plugin options page), then you should use the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook instead of `wp_enqueue_scripts` (or use `login_enqueue_scripts` on the login page). You should also ensure that `$plugin_url . 'style.css'` outputs the correct URL.

Comment: test() is being used on a regular WP page.  Do I use a leading /style.css or just style.css?

Comment: If you use `plugin_dir_url()`, then `style.css` would work fine, i.e. the leading `/` is not needed. However, in what file did you put the code in the question? Is it in your main plugin file and are you actually referring to a standalone plugin in `wp-content/plugins`? Can you answer that by editing your question and preferably, show your plugin structure (the directory tree).

Comment: Edited my question to show the directory.

Comment: So that means you have `player-match/pm_main.php` and `player-match/style.css`, right? And `pm_main.php` is the main plugin file with the `Plugin Name:` header, is it? How are you actually calling `test()`; is it hooked on any hook? Can you add the details to your post? Because your code looks good to me, except that `wp_enqueue_style()` should only be called in the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook. So please edit your post and include *as much details as possible*.

Comment: Also, if you inspect the page/HTML source, do you see a `<link rel="stylesheet">` having `/wp-content/plugins/player-match/style.css` in the `src`?